# Grammar for ordinal numbers greater than 10

Tags: numbers

Saluton!

It is to my understanding that ordinal numbers are constructed with a ***-a*** prefix.

First - 1st - unua
Second - 2nd - dua
~
Tenth - 10th - deka

Based on this, would "eleventh" be ***deka unua*** or ***dek unua***?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *-a* is only added to the last word so your example would be *dek unua*.

It’s also quite common to write the ordinal numbers as a single word such as *dek-unua*. Apparently neither way is more official because the Fundamento itself uses both so it is a matter of preference. Personally I quite like it as one word.

PMEG has [much more detail](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/a-vortoj.html#i-oaj) on this.

Comment: I guess you meant *ordinal* numbers

Comment: @marcus, yes, I did. Thanks, I’ve edited it.